# SignalR Alternative for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, signalr, tornado

What would be an alternative for SignalR in Python world?

To be precise, I am using tornado with python 2.7.6 on Windows 8; and I found [sockjs-tornado](https://github.com/MrJoes/sockjs-tornado) (Python noob; sorry for any inconveniences). But sockjs supports just 3 types of events and there are [some limitations](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client); I need things like groups, subscribers, propagating and other features that SignalR provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for Twisted, a whole real-time engine for  applications. https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

If you do microframeworks, Flask (think Sinatra on ruby) also has a real-time module, but it's all barebones really, it might not be what you're looking for:

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Cheers.

Comment: Back then I was working with `Tornado` which I enjoyed very much. The Python branch of the project though dropped dead. So it's been some time that I do not Python. So I am not qualified to judge the answer provided. But I'll keep an eye for upvotes; Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is SignalPy.
https://pypi.org/project/SignalPy/

SignalPy
Real-time Communication for web applications with SignalPy. Incredibly simple real-time web for python WSGI servers and frameworks

I am the author of signalpy.
report bugs or ask questions :https://github.com/Ksengine/SignalPy/issues
If anyone can please contribute.