# Using Python to communicate with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

Is there a way to send data packets from an active Python script to a webpage currently running JavaScript?

The specific usage I'm looking for is to give the ability for the webpage, using JavaScript, to tell the Python script information about the current state of the webpage, then for the Python script to interpret that data and then send data back to the webpage, which the JavaScript then uses to decide which function to execute.

This is for a video game bot (legally), so it would need to happen in real time. I'm fairly proficient in Python and web requests, but I'm just getting into JavaScript, so hopefully a solution for this wouldn't be too complex in terms of Javascript.

EDIT: One way I was thinking to accomplish this would be to have Javascript write to a file that the Python script could also read and write to, but a quick google search says that JavaScript is very limited in terms of file I/O. Would there be a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Related (almost duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413568/signalr-alternative-for-python

Comment: You are going to need a websocket in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, javascript in a browser is usually restricted to only communicate with the site it was loaded from.

Given that, that's an AJAX call, a very standard thing to do.

Comment: An AJAX call? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can make HTTP requests using the XMLHttpRequest API, which Jquery abstracts with $.ajax and $.get. You can also use the lower level Websockets network API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

Note that the XMLHttpRequest API will only allow requests to the same server, OR requests that return an appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Javascript is only going to send information, not receive any. In that case, you're in luck. I'm guessing you are also running the Javascript and the Python on the same machine.

Run a Python webserver on the machine the browser is running on. Here's a simple example:

http://webpy.org/install

Once visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` in your browser gives the message `Hello World!`, you can start adding more addresses to your website, for example `http://127.0.0.1:8080/report_data`, `http://127.0.0.1:8080/report_event` etc.

Your Javascript can then make AJAX requests using `jQuery.ajax` or `XMLHTTPRequest`, to the address `http://127.0.0.1:8080/report_data`, and pass the information as `GET` parameters.

Comment: Sorry, that's inaccurate. I need Python to be able to send information to JavaScript in order for Javascript to execute functions based on the information that Python processed.

Comment: Then you can encode the data in Python using `json.dumps`, and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response using `web.header`, and in the browser, use `JSON.parse` to read the response.